# How to concatenate constant string with jsonpath

Tags: jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I have AWS step machine and one of the step is used to notify failure using SNS service. I want to select some metadata from `input` json into outgoing message. So i am trying to concatenate constant string with jsonpath like below

```
"Notify Failure": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
      "Parameters": {
        "Message.$": "A job submitted through Step Functions failed for document id $.document_id",
        "Subject":"Job failed",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx"
      },
      "End": true
    }
```

where `document_id` is one of the property in input json

However when i try save state machine defination i get error

> There is a problem with your ASL definition, please review it and try
>   again The value for the field 'Message.$' must be a valid JSONPath

Answer (score 65):

I was able to solve a similar issue using:

```
"Message.$": "States.Format('A job submitted through Step Functions failed for document id {}', $.document_id)",
```

Described in a [AWS News Blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-step-functions-adds-updates-to-choice-state-global-access-to-context-object-dynamic-timeouts-result-selection-and-intrinsic-functions-to-amazon-states-languages/).

Comment: Amazing, been looking for this for days, thank you! Docs here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html

Answer (score 4):

I know that this thread is quite old, but I think it might be useful for some people.

**It IS actually possible to concatenate strings or JSONPaths** in AWS Step Functions thanks to the function *States.Format*.

The principle is the same as the string *format* method in Python.

#### Example with strings

```
"States.Format('{}<separator_1>{}<separator_2>{}', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz')"
```

will give you

```
'foo<separator_1>bar<separator_2>baz'
```

#### Example with JSONPaths

```
"States.Format('{}<separator>{}', $.param_1, $.param_2)"
```

will give you

```
'<value of param_1><separator><value of param_2>'
```

**NB:** You can also combine strings with JSONPaths.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Adding clarification. The occurrences of {} indicate where parameters should be placed. "separator" is not really a separator -- it can be any desired text, or nothing at all if parameters should appear with no separation. So as example, where $.inputparam = "inpath": "States.Format('I want {} to go here, and {} goes there. I also want input parameter to be {}{}', 'param 1', 'param 2', 'right here: ', $.inputparam" will result in the output "I want param 1 to go here, and param 2 goes there. I also want input parameter to be right here: inpath".

Answer (score 3):

The JSONPath implementation referenced from the AWS Step Functions documentation [supports String concatenation](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/blob/78c04fc48f3b4c339ece14469c255e9b4bb9c473/json-path/src/main/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/function/text/Concatenate.java) via `$.concat($..prop)` but sadly this does not work when deployed to AWS, suggesting that AWS uses a different implementation.

Therefore there is no way to do string concatenation with JSONPath in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

As the message suggest you need to provide a valid JSONPath.

`"Message.$": "$.document_id"`

You cannot use any string interpolation as it invalidates the JSONPath format. You will need to construct the message in the preceding state.

Comment: Even in the preceding state how would you do that if I cannot cancatinate. And creating lambda just for concatenation is too much

Comment: the state that set $.document_id needs to set full string.

Comment: also when there is an exception in preceding state, it passes the error to `Notify Failure` state, The error would not have `$document_id`

Comment: Perhaps do a try/catch in your preceding state and then construct some sort of json output like `{ "error_message": "Failed for document id {document_id}" }`. This becomes part of your `ResultPath` that you can pass through to the next state.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with the `AWS CDK` like this:

```js
import {
  aws_stepfunctions as sfn,
  aws_stepfunctions_tasks as tasks,
} from "aws-cdk-lib";

sfn.JsonPath.format(
            "s3://{}/{}",
            sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.detail.bucket.name"),
            sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.detail.object.key"),
          )
```